# How to get notified of changes in an RSS feed

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, rss, rss-reader

I need to populate a database with data from an RSS feed. Is there anyway to ensure that I don't populate the database with duplicate information?

I don't want to compare data in the database to determine if I have duplicate information as thi would be very slow.

Similar to this question [How to detect changed and new items in an RSS feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700607/how-to-detect-changed-and-new-items-in-an-rss-feed) but the answer is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I think that answer is what you are looking for, what kind of answer do you want then?

Answer (score 2):

You will usually want to use the [GUID-Element of an Item](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#ltguidgtSubelementOfLtitemgt) to perform duplicate-checks.

If you already know the guid of an item, it was already seen by you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the title of your question and your description of it do not match :)

If you want to get notified when an RSS feed updates, you'll have to use the [PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) protocol which is designed for that. It will only work though if the publisher supports it in its feeds. You can also check [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) for all other feeds. (I created Superfeedr!).

Now, if you're wondering how to make sure you do not save the same data twice, the recommanded method is to map the `<GUID>` element for RSS, or the `<id>`element for Atom in your datastore. It will involve comparing all of these items in a feed with the ones you've previoulsy stored. It should not be too costly for most feeds as they usually don't include hundreds of entries.

Comment: Hey Julien, Superfeedr looks really good - if  I understood it right, I'll be able to get notified by superfeedr when there is a change in the feed? It looks a bit complicated - but I will try work it out.

Comment: Yes, you understood right. And to be even more complete, the notification will include whatever is new in the feed, so you won't even have to go get it.